# Create a hg bookmark after committing a changeset

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I cloned a Mercurial repo and made some changes in the checked out code. I then grabbed those changes (7 files) and committed them with `hg commit` but without having created a bookmark first.

This is the output of my `hg summary` command:

```
parent: 8172:b39efc1322fe tip
  Made some changes in my feature
branch: default
commit: 7 modified
update: 2 new changesets, 3 branch heads (merge)
phases: 3 draft
```

These changes won't be ready to be pushed for at least another week, so I want to switch to a new bookmark and work on other parts of the code.

The problem is that I realized that I had made a commit without being in a bookmark, so I'm afraid that after switching to a new bookmark my committed changes could be lost.

Is there an easy way to move these committed changes into a new bookmark?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no need to be afraid at all: mercurial won't forget anything you committed unless you explicitly do both: enable history editing extensions and willingly use them in a way that you actually remove one or more changesets.

Mercurial is not git and mercurial does never forget or garbage-collect a changeset when it is not currently checked out and has no name (bookmark) attached to it.

You can show you all your heads using `hg heads`. And you can always create new bookmarks, attached to an arbitrary changeset by `hg bookmark --rev XXX MyBookmark` where XXX is the changesetID to which you want to attach the bookmark.

Answer (score -4):

> I'm afraid that after switching to a new bookmark my committed changes could be lost.

How can you imagine *this*? OMFG, you committed your changes to repository (your clone), you have this changeset (`8172:b39efc1322fe`) in it. When|if you'll `svn up` to another node, you'll just **change parent of your Working Directory**, on pull you'll get "2 new changeset" and, as result "3 branch heads" - 2 new changesets + your commit 8172, and this `b39efc1322fe` will be always one of heads, even you'll up and work in another.

If you are afraid to forget it (*how??? really*), you can post-fact bookmark this (committed) changeset with `hg bookmark -r b39efc1322fe $WIP && hg commit -m "Bookmarked my work"` in order to `hg up $WIP` when it will be time to continue this chunk of changes

Comment: No need to be snarky - it's a legitimate question to want to move the commit to a new bookmark, whether or not the fear is founded.